# Red Hat Fuse Quickstarts all "Pending'

Tags: groovy, apache-camel, jbossfuse

All the beginner Camel quickstart projects fail to build similar to the following...

```
An internal error occurred during: "Loading camel-log.xml of project beginner-camel-log-wiki".
```

Could not initialize class groovy.grape.GrapeIvy

I have tried clean all and tried finding the maven repository where it can be found but no luck.  I tried mvn clean install from the command line in the project root but no luck.

I added this dependency to the pom and did another clean, still no luck.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

and

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ivy/ivy -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
   <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I was able to install Groovy in my CodeReady 12.17 but could not install Ivy with the following errors on install...

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
```

Software being installed: a.jre.javase 11.0.0
Software currently installed: Red Hat CodeReady Studio (Branded Product) 12.17.0.GA-v20201001-1023-B6979 (com.jboss.devstudio.core.package 12.17.0.GA-v20201001-1023-B6979)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Red Hat CodeReady Studio (Branded Product) 12.17.0.GA-v20201001-1023-B6979 (com.jboss.devstudio.core.package 12.17.0.GA-v20201001-1023-B6979)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; a.jre.javase [1.7.0,12.0.0)

I have jdk 15.0.1 and jre 1.8.0 installed in my environment.

Comment: But what did you try to do? Run the quickstarts? Build the quickstarts? Which version? 6, 7? Which platform - Karaf? Spring Boot? EAP? OpenShift?

Comment: Sorry, I was building with the latest CodeReady Studio, version 12.17. It will run on Karaf which is installed and running.  I have been trying to install Ivy given the error on build.  But get errors I will add to my post.

Comment: `To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; a.jre.javase [1.7.0,12.0.0)` means you can't use JDK 15. you have to use JDK 1.7 - 11.0.

Comment: ok thanks will try that

Comment: I have installe1.7 and jdk 11 and added to the eclipse installed jre's to no avail.

Comment: But did the error message change?